# What unit does scipy's kdtree function return distance in?

Tags: python, scipy, spatial, kdtree

I'm new to KD trees and I'm using them to find the nearest neighbour for each point in one array (search_array), compared with all the points in a second array (vec_array).

Both arrays are formatted like so:

```
array([[ 51.54094696,   0.09767043],
   [ 51.53620148,   0.0798    ],
   [ 51.53620148,   0.0798    ],
   ..., 
   [ 51.54118347,  -0.08202313],
   [ 48.84996033,   2.32329845],
   [ 40.42570496,  -3.70100427]])
```

Here is my code:

```
def kdtree(search_points, vec_points):
mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(search_points)
dist, indexes = mytree.query(vec_points)
return indexes, dist

result = kdtree(vec_array,search_array)
```

And the output:

```
(array([1361, 1339, 1339, ..., 1139, 1766, 1711]),
array([ 0.01365104,  0.00059667,  0.00059667, ...,  0.00151025,
         0.00754338,  0.00203098]))
```

The second array is clearly the distances but I can't work out what unit it is in, I'd be very grateful if somebody could enlighten me!

Comment: The units are the same units as the input array.  For example, the distance between the first two points in your input array is `np.sqrt((51.54094696 - 51.53620148)**2 + (0.09767043 - 0.0798)**2) = 0.018489776873052591`.  Are those numbers not what you expected?

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33741302/1461210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kindly indicated by Warren in the comment above, the units are the same as in the input array.